# How do I use an external font like Impact for my android app?

Tags: android, fonts, assets, typeface

I would like to use the external font Impact on my android app. Currently the code that lets me use my font looks like this:

```
    Paint textPaint = new Paint();
    textPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    textPaint.setTextSize(FONT_SIZE);
    textPaint.setColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
    Log.i(TAG, "- Paint: " + textPaint);

    Typeface face = textPaint.getTypeface();
    Log.i(TAG, "- default typeface: " + face);

    face = Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD;
    Log.i(TAG, "- new face: " + face);
    textPaint.setTypeface(face);
```

but that results in a bad generic version of the font I want to use. For those of you not familiar with the Impact font, its the font that allows you to make meme's. Does anyone know what I should do to be able to use Impact font instead of the DEFAULT_BOLD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `canvas` to draw text,

```
Typeface  mFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),"fonts/samplefont.ttf");
Paint mPaint = new Paint ();
mPaint.setTypeface(mFace);
canvas.drawText("Default", 10, 100, mPaint);
```

`TextView` can use `setTypeface` method to do this;

Comment: To add onto this, you have to have the font file in your `res/assets` directory, in pswwei's example, in a `fonts/` subdirectory. Be sure the font's license allows redistribution and use before you ship off!

Comment: Wow this works perfectly! I had to get rid of the `canvas.drawText` and then changed  `textPaint.setTypeface(face);` to  `textPaint.setTypeface(mFace);`